# Convert String to Dict in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I am trying to convert the below type of string into Dictionary in Python.

```
'F1=Value1,F2=Value2,F3=[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]],F6=Value6'
```

I would like to make the dictionary like:

```
{
    'F1': 'Value1', 
    'F2': 'Value2',
    'F3': '[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]]',
    'F6': 'Value6'
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem you've run into? The ideal solution would be to [use JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead of an arbitrary format, but if that's not an option, you'll get better answers here if you show you're putting in the work but need a help with specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you will continue to use the identical string format, you may use a complex regular expression to cover various patterns.

The following is a regular expression for a few patterns I have anticipated. Let me know if this solves your issue. If not, please provide details on where my solution fails:

Edit for explaining

1. Group one `(?=F\d+=\[).*?(\]){2,}(?=|,)`

   - `(?=F\d+=\[)` match string begin with F, have one or more numbers, and have `=[` after them
   - `.*?(\]){2,}` match string as less as it can, and it have 2 or more `]` at the end
   - `(?=|,)` the string end `,` or nothing
2. Group two  `F\d.[^,]+`

   - after matching group one, it is easy to find the string like `F6=Value6`. because the first group takes precedence over the second group, so the second group can only match the remaining strings.

Code

```
string = "F1=Value1,F2=Value2,F3=[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]],F6=Value6,F7=[[[BC],[AC]]]"
import re
resultset = [ele[0] if ele[0] else ele[-1] for ele in re.findall(r"((?=F\d+=\[).*?(\]){2,}(?=|,))|(F\d.[^,]+)",string)]
print({x[:x.find("=")]:x[x.find("=")+1:] for x in resultset})
```

Output

```
{'F6': 'Value6', 'F2': 'Value2', 'F3': '[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]]', 'F1': 'Value1', 'F7': '[[[BC],[AC]]]'}
```

Edit: because the former regex does not work when string is `F1=Value1,F2=Value2,F8=[iD=10,ig=12S],F3=[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]],F6=Value6,F9=[iD=10,ig=12S],F7=[[[BC],[AC]]]`

I changed regex to `((?=F\d+=\[).*?(\])+(?= |,F))|(F\d.[^,]+)`. And we need one trick. *add one blankspace after string*.

```
string = "F1=Value1,F2=Value2,F8=[iD=10,ig=12S],F3=[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]],F6=Value6,F9=[iD=10,ig=12S],F7=[[[BC],[AC]]]"
import re
resultset = [ele[0] if ele[0] else ele[-1] for ele in re.findall(r"((?=F\d+=\[).*?(\])+(?= |,F))|(F\d.[^,]+)",string+" ")]
print({x[:x.find("=")]:x[x.find("=")+1:] for x in resultset})
```

Comment: @netbbq This is the victory of priority matching

Comment: Make your example a bit more complicated, you code doesn't work any more as below. "F1=Value1,F2=Value2,F8=[iD=10,ig=12S],F3=[[F4=Value4,F5=Value5]],F6=Value6,F9=[iD=10,ig=12S],F7=[[[BC],[AC]]]"